# python 3 problema en línea de código usando módulo sys

Tags: python-3.x

éste es parte del código de un ejercício en donde encontré el problema.

import sys
class Individual :

```
def _init_ ():
    valid_genders = ["male" , "female" , "other"]
employee_name = input ("enter name of the employee :  ")
print()
employee_age = input ("enter the age of the employee :  ")
print()
print ("gender values are ")
print()
print ("1. male")
print()
print ("2. female")
print()
print ("3. other")
print()
try :
    employee_gender = input ("enter gender of the employee :  ")
    print()
    if employee_gender not in valid_genders :
        raise Exception ("ValuError")
except Exception as ValueError :
    print ("please , enter a valid gender")
sys.exit (0)
```

y el problema es que al ejecutar debería imprimír el tipo de género elegído por el usuario (male , female , other) sin embargo sólo se ejecúta...

```
print ("please , enter a valid gender")
```

o sea, sin importar la respuesta que ingrese, siempre muestra el mísmo print. no sé que le falta para que impríma la respuesta al ejecutar y el programa continúe con el resto del código.

Comment: `python` es sensible a los espacios/tabulaciones. Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/443206/edit) tu código y asegúrate de que está correctamente formateado y exactamente igual que lo tienes en tu máquina.

Comment: sí, no sé por qué no se copió bien el código. quedó mal posicionado todo.

Answer (score 0):

no has declarado import sys, no mandas a llamar a employee_gender  despues de la comparación, tampoco estas definiendo la lista a comparar "def *init* (valid_genders )", y en ningur lugar muestras el genero de la persona un ejemplo "print("The chosen gender is")
print(employee_gender)" , revisa las condiciones y las excepciones para que no te genere ese error.

Comment: sí gracias, revisando varias veces he notado que probáblemente el código está escríto en una versión de python diferente a la mía. al parecer tengo que corregír mucha de la sintáxis para que funcione el código. voy a votar para eliminar la pregunta porque no tiene sentído si la cosa viene por ahí.